# Have a table-cell spanning entire table with automatic width

Tags: tables, width, multicolumn

I'm formatting a table, and I the bottom row has to have the "table notes". I'm not allowed to use the `threeparttable` package (or any other special package).
I know I can use something like

```
\multicolumn{ncols}{p{10cm}}{Contents}
```

or

```
\multicolumn{ncols}{p{0.8\textwidth}}{Contents}
```

but I want the width of this cell to be computed automatically: it should be the width of the table, so something like `\tablewidth` (but that one doesn't exist).

Is this possible? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.